# Could not launch cscope in RHEL

Tags: linux, cscope

I could not launch cscope.I am getting the following error,

```
    [naveen@hello]$ cscope -d
    cscope: Could not create private temp dir /tmp/cscope.9344
```

I have the following files in the same folder which is related to cscope.

```
    [naveen@hello]$ls
    :
    cscope.files
    cscope.in.out
    cscope.out
    cscope.po.out
    tags
    :
```

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Maybe figure out why it can't create directories in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check following

- if you have enough free storage on `/tmp/`
- if the user with which you are running `cscope` has write permission
  to `/tmp/`.
- try to change the temporary directory location by setting value for
  `TMPDIR` e.g. `TMPDIR=/var/tmp`

The man page cscope is [here](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html)

Comment: Yes.I don't have enough space.after cleanup some files i am able to launch cscope.

Comment: Then either make it larger, or change the `TMPDIR` to another directory where you have enough storage

Answer (score 0):

Check the following,

$ sudo cscope -d